# Как проверить пустое значение в списке?

Tags: python, массивы, list

Работаю над ботом ВК, пишу команду для бана.
Для начало беру весь текст, что пишет пользователь:

```
target = event.object['message'].get('text')[5:]
nkd = target.split('|')[0]
ban_id = re.findall(r'id(.*)', nkd)[0]

i = f"{target}"
string = i.split()
print(string)

>>> ['[id539995337|@karl.rendal]', 'test', '999']
```

Хочу сделать проверку на то, что пусты ли остальные значения:

```
if string[1] and string[2] == 0:
        print('NONE')

>>> if string[1] and string[2] == 0: 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Может возможно как-то создать пустые значения в списке, чтобы уже потом их проверять?

```
['[id539995337|@karl.rendal]', '', '']
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы было 3 значения?

Comment: @КириллМалышев, Нет, два. Первое значение получается за счёт того, что я пишу /ban @kar.rendal test 999. Весь текст просто берётся `target = event.object['message'].get('text')[5:]`

Comment: Но тут их 3 `['[id539995337|@karl.rendal]', '', '']`

Comment: @КириллМалышев, А вот вы про что, я думал, что нужно брать. Ну получается что три, но нужно взять всего лишь два последних.

Comment: Вам подходит мой ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
l.extend([''] * (3 - len(l)))
```

Или так:

```
res = l + [''] * (3 - len(l))
```

Comment: Я надеюсь, я правильно сделал.. https://pastebin.com/wmra4SzW

Comment: @hoojpop, `extend` меняет исходный список и ничего не возвращает. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Извиняюсь, что долго не отвечал.